# How to stop while loop when it reaches the goal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

As I show in the below, I have a function that prints year and month. But I want it to stop when it reaches a point.

```
month = 0
year = 0
for i in range(7):
    month = month + 3
    print(year, month)
    while month > 9:
        month = 0
        year = year + 1
        month = month + 3
        print(year, month)
```

I mean if `(month + year * 12) > 15`, it must stop to print value. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Please update your question with the function that you speak of.

Comment: You probably want to read about the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement. BTW, your while loop will only run once anyway, so I don't think there is what to `break` from...

Comment: as @Tomerikoo suggests, read about the `break` statement. As to why your code doesn't seem to need one: as you can see from the output, the first values are `year=0` and `month=3`. `(0 + 3 * 12) == 36 > 15`.

Comment: @mlg556 as you said if it is 36 and is bigger than 15 then it should stop and i have used break but it did not work as i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding with for loop you can add the condition in while loop as follows:

```
month = 0
year = 0
while (month + year * 12) < 15:
    month = month + 3
    print(year, month)
    while month > 9:
        month = 0
        year = year + 1
        month = month + 3
        print(year, month)
```